# цвет фона окна и текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, rgb

встала задача поменять цвет фона окна и текста.
попробовал вот-так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()
Dialog.setStyleSheet("#Dialog{color: rgb(170, 255, 0);,background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}")
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: Егор, а зачем вы удалили вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394755 и создали точно такой же вопрос?

Comment: ответе пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем запятые между свойствами?

```
("#Dialog{color: rgb(170, 255, 0);,background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}"
```

Разделителем служит \n а не запятая!

Формы проще и удобнее создавать через qtcreator